# Is it possible to use dotTrace within a virtual machine?

Tags: profiling, virtualization, dottrace

I've been trying to run dotTrace 3.1 on my Windows 7 development machine. However, it turns out that dotTrace 3.1 doesn't work on Windows 7 properly.  I've been in a discussion with JetBrains regarding this who confirms that it is a known issue that won't be addressed until the next release.

I'm considering setting up a virtual machine with either VMWare or Virtual PC and installing dotTrace in the VM.

My question is fairly straight forward: Will dotTrace work within a virtual machine?

I'm going to do some memory profiling, and I think that this might imply some problems when using a virtual machine, since I reckon the virtual machine will use some kind of virtual address space instead of the physical RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses virtual memory whether it runs in a VM or not. doTrace should work fine running in vmware or similar.

Comment: At least for the performance part of dotTrace I can tell that a Windows 7 OS on a VMWare virtual box runs fine. I used version 4.5.1 of dotTrace.